# Can't create a new lua project

Tags: eclipse, lua

I just downloaded the Lua Development Tools plugin for eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/ldt/). But when I want to create a project (I highlight the lua project type and hit `Next`), nothing happens. When I doubleclick `Lua project`, I get an error:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com/naef/jnlua/LuaException
```

Could anyone point me into the right direction and tell me whats causing this weird behaviour? 
By the way, my eclipse version:

```
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
```

**EDIT:** okay, browsed the log for anything useful, and it seems like I've found something.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lua5.1 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.naef.jnlua.internal.osgi.Activator.start(Activator.java:30)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
... 74 more
```

Comment: I bet its something really stupid.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install Lua in your machine.

For Linux machine is easy as type in console:

> sudo apt-get -y -q install lua5.1

For Mac OS X there is a tutorial here: [Running Lua on Mac OS X](http://rudamoura.com/luaonmacosx.html).

And for Windows there is a project in github: [Lua for Windows](https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows).

A good editor to work with Lua is SciTE.

You can find more answers at lua.org